# cancel key when max length reached

Tags: jquery, html

I have a textarea which I would like to restrict the length (Of course its checked at server-side).

So I have

```
<textarea id="myFunkyTextArea" maxlength="255"></textarea>
```

I tried the following

```
$('#myDiv').delegate('textarea','keydown',function(evt){
  console.log($(this).val().lenth > 255)
  if ($(this).val().lenth > 255){
    //tried
    //return false
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

I know how to pick up the maxlength attr but I just trying to cancel the event so that their input is not added to the the textarea. The reason I went with keydown is so if the person holds down a single key it should reach 255 and stop adding that key to the textarea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [limit number of characters entered in textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805678/limit-number-of-characters-entered-in-textarea) [and lots of others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+limit+text+length+textarea)

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestions. Try the noble-count plugin http://tpgblog.com/noblecount/
It gives your great control of your textarea.

Answer (score 0):

your code itself should work if you return false; and in that code length spelling is wrong. check it down.