# Limit the textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [limit number of characters entered in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805678/limit-number-of-characters-entered-in-textarea)

How can I set a limit on the number of characters possible to go into a textarea? I have a textarea that you can put max 50 characters into it. How can i make this with Javascript. I want that the enters are also characters so people wont put lots of `enters`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function imposeMaxLength(Object, MaxLen)
{
  return (Object.value.length <= MaxLen);
}
</script> 

<textarea name="myName" onkeypress="return imposeMaxLength(this, 15);" ><textarea>
```

or

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    } else {
        limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
    }
}
</script>

<form name="myform">
    <textarea name="limitedtextarea" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,100);" 
onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,100);">
    </textarea><br>
    <font size="1">(Maximum characters: 100)<br>
    You have <input readonly type="text" name="countdown" size="3" value="100"> characters left.</font>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

the above code with onkeypress will not work with copy/paste or drag & drop
you can use the "oninput" event but it is not supported in all mayor browsers (ie8+)
the best way to limit/filter a form field is this:

```
<form id="a" method="post" action="?hey">
<textarea id="t" data-maxlen="10"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit me">
</form>

<script>
var aa = document.getElementById("a");
var tt = document.getElementById("t");
aa.onsubmit=function()
{
    if(tt.value.length > parseInt(tt.getAttribute("data-maxlen")))
    {
        tt.style.backgroundColor="red";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        tt.style.backgroundColor="white";
        return true;
    }
};
</script>
```

but in any case you will need a server-side check

HTH!